# MS DNS server - Is zone transfer really enabled on Cache and how to disable?

Tags: networking, security, dns, cache

I was reviewing the configuration of my Microsoft DNS server by executing `dnscmd localhost /exportsettings` and then going through the  `C:\Windows\system32\dns\DnsSettings.txt` file. As I understood the [`SecureSecondaries`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940802.aspx) displays the the zonetransfer settings. If it is set to 0 (meaning "Disable secondary security. Send zone transfers to all secondary servers that request them."), it is a security risk as [discussed here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10457/123648) (it can reveal sensitive information about the network topology).

However in the `DnsSettings.txt` file `SecureSecondaries` is set to `0` for the `Cache` zone:

```
[Zones]

Cache=Cache,AD-integrated
*removed*


[Cache]

Type=Cache
Store=AD-integrated
AllowUpdate=0
ZoneDN=DC=RootDNSServers,cn=MicrosoftDNS,DC=*removed*
DirectoryPartition=*removed*
SecureSecondaries=0
Secondaries=NULL
NotifyList=NULL
```

However I can not find where it can be disabled in the DNS Manager application, and the command given by Microsoft: `dnscmd localhost /ZoneResetSecondaries Cache /NoXfr` returns `Command failed: DNS_ERROR_ZONE_DOES_NOT_EXIST 9601 0x2581`.

Is DNS zone transfer really enabled for the Cache zone, or as Cache is not a master zone it can not be enabled at all? If it is enabled, how can I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cache is not a zone.  It's merely a placeholder for the current list of DNS root servers.  Hence the error you see...  dnscmd can't find a zone called "cache".  It's real name is "." but is still not a real zone just a special boot-strapping construct.  So secondary settings don't matter.